# Browse, open a PDF file, add a stamp to page 1, then save it as a new file python

Tags: python, image, pdf, tkinter, save

I have these lines of codes to browse/open a pdf, add a stamp/image to page 1, then save it as a new file. But when I run the code, it is not saving the new pdf file. Any help is greatly appreciated, I am very new to python.

```
import tkinter
import fitz
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog


main_win = tkinter.Tk()
main_win.geometry("500x500")
main_win.sourceFolder = ''
main_win.sourceFile = ''
def chooseDir():
    main_win.sourceFolder =  filedialog.askdirectory(parent=main_win, initialdir= "/", title='Please select a directory')

b_chooseDir = tkinter.Button(main_win, text = "Chose Folder", width = 20, height = 3, command = chooseDir)
b_chooseDir.place(x = 50,y = 50)
b_chooseDir.width = 100


def chooseFile():
    main_win.sourceFile = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=main_win, initialdir= "/", title='Please select a directory')

def convertFile():
    dst_pdf_filename = 'destination.pdf'
    img_filename = 'hillsborough county stamp.png'
  
    img_rect = fitz.Rect(55, 28, 180, 390)
    
    page = document[0]
    page.insertImage(img_rect, filename=img_filename)
  
    document.save(dst_pdf_filename)
    document.close()
    
b_chooseFile = tkinter.Button(main_win, text = "Chose File", width = 20, height = 3, command = chooseFile)
b_chooseFile.place(x = 250,y = 50)
b_chooseFile.width = 100

b_convertFile = tkinter.Button(main_win, text = "Convert File", width = 20, height = 3, command = convertFile)
b_convertFile.place(x = 250,y = 200)
b_convertfile.width = 100


main_win.mainloop()
print(main_win.sourceFolder)
print(main_win.sourceFile )
```

Comment: Do you know that all code behind `mainloop()` will only be executed after closing the root window?

Comment: ops, codes have been updated. Still having the same issue

Comment: `src_pdf_filename` is not defined in your code.

Comment: add button to run function which will save file. If you run `document.save(dst_pdf_filename)` directly then it is executed before you even see window. GUIs works different then console script with `input()` - `mainloop` starts window and all code before `mainloop` is executed before you see windows - so it is executed before you choose file, etc. You have to use buttons to run code in expected moment - when window is displayed.

Comment: Code modified, it still won't add image to page 1 and won't save. I am definitely doing something very wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand, you want to add a stamp image in the source file `main_win.sourceFile` and save it to new file `dst_pdf_filename`:

```py
def convertFile():
    if main_win.sourceFile:
        dst_pdf_filename = 'destination.pdf'
        img_filename = 'hillsborough county stamp.png'

        img_rect = fitz.Rect(55, 28, 180, 390)

        document = fitz.open(main_win.sourceFile) # open source file
        page = document[0]
        page.insertImage(img_rect, filename=img_filename)

        document.save(dst_pdf_filename)
        document.close()
```